Vscode cannot access R help documents
I am currently learning and writing R by Vscode and Just today, I met a problem that I cannot access the help pages after typing ? function in the R interactive terminal.
This is the Error message that I got:
Error Message Picture
Here is my setup:
Windows 11 (already up to date)
Vscode User Setting:
{
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "accessibility.signals.lineHasError": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.lineHasFoldedArea": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.lineHasBreakpoint": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.lineHasInlineSuggestion": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.onDebugBreak": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.noInlayHints": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.taskCompleted": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.notebookCellCompleted": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.notebookCellFailed": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.diffLineInserted": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.diffLineDeleted": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "accessibility.signals.diffLineModified": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "accessibility.signals.progress": {
        "sound": "off"
    },
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-44~1.1/bin/x64",
    "r.helpPanel.cacheIndexFiles": "None"
}

Also, I have already tried Clear Cache & Restart Help Server and it keeps running forever
Can someone suggests a possible solution? Thank you!

What does options('help_type') typed in R console give you?

Does it work if you don't include the parentheses () after the function?

Hi Jay, the command gives me html

Have you verified the directory & files named in the error message exist, and have the "read bit" enabled?
